# django- how to have a common list for anonymous and logged in user

Tags: django, django-views, django-sessions

i have a list on my website which remains same for both anonymous and logged-in users. I use session dictionary to store the data.But when I logout I lose the session values as the django.contrib.auth.views.logout uses session.flush().....If I make a custom logout by removing the sessions.flush() ,I am not able to log-out. Can someone tell me how override the flush()..or some other by which we can create a common list for anonymous and logged-in users.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where/what are the list values coming from? Objects from a model? Why do you need to attach them into a session? Might be a better way to do it depending on the task.

Comment: yup..values are obtained from an object..see basically i have products on my website. I m creating a shortlist which has to remain same for anonymous and logged in users

Comment: Are users and anonymous users being able to add to the list or is it just a query you're setting on your own? If the latter, you could just do lists = Products.objects.all() , add 'lists' to context for the template and output it there without messing around with any sessions. I suppose I still don't see why you're using sessions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have a list called 'user_list'

```
def logout_view(logout):
    # Do whatever pre conditions you have here.
    my_list = request.session['user_list']
    logout(request)
    # Now Django would have flushed your previous sessions and created a new session.
    request.session['user_list'] = my_list
    return HttpResponse() # Or render to response i.e whatever you do.
```

Now make sure that a session is being created for anonymous user also. And rest everything will work. Hope it does for you.